# Have invites and user in tab or side by side

Tags: users, tabs

I'm having a bit of trouble deciding which of the two would be better UX practice.

Below are two versions:

- One with user and invite tabs.
- Another with user and invite information side by side.

[image: Version 1, with tabs]

[image: Version 2, invite and user side by side]

Please let me know what you guys think. The target group is middle aged if that helps. 
Thanks!

Comment: Can you explain what this UI is for? Right now I don't understand the association between users and invites. Are they associated? What's this being used for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this design is for desktop application (due to the fact that the second option would not work for mobile), I prefer the second option with the blocks, because it eliminate a user click and maintains everything that is related in the field of view.

But if the task of invitations is not so important, you can leave it in the form of tabs that would work very well and will not pollute the user's screen, making it more comfortable.

> Use tabs to alternate between views within the same context, not to
>   navigate to different areas. This is the single most important point,
>   because staying in place while alternating views is the reason we have
>   tabs in the first place.

So, just know whether it is an important task or not, to hide or make visible.

See more: https://www.nngroup.com/articles/tabs-used-right/

Answer (score 0):

I will choose the first option. Because I found that both tab labels are associated. The "USERS" tab is the person you accepted the invitation. The "INVITE" tab shows the user who are invites and waiting for your acceptance.

If we put them into 2 blocks, I will feel both content are different.

[image]